# Edit text file on server using javascript/jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get a text file from my server and present it in a html form. Then after the user have edited it I want the text to be saved and overwrited to the text file.

I know getting content from a server file is possible with jQuery AJAX, but is it possible to save and overwriting the text to a file (e.g .txt)?

Comment: [Read/Write Server side files ~ jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021877/read-write-server-side-files-comment-board-jquery)

Comment: Thanks! If I got it right, it is possible to get text, but not to save. To save, I need to use a language as PHP.

Comment: @RasmusM exactly yes. You submit the contents of the form back to the server, and use a server-side language (such as PHP, ASP.NET, node.js etc.) to take that data and save it back to the text file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.